# Shuffle a numpy array without mutation

Tags: numpy

[`np.random.Generator#shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html) shuffles a numpy array in-place.

How do I shuffle a numpy array without mutating the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html) `Generator` method.

For example,

```
In [6]: rng = np.random.default_rng()

In [7]: x = np.arange(10)

In [8]: x
Out[8]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Create a randomly shuffled copy of `x`:

```
In [9]: rng.permuted(x)
Out[9]: array([3, 5, 8, 0, 4, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9])
```

Check that `x` is not changed:

```
In [10]: x
Out[10]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.random.Generator#permutation`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permutation.html) to shuffle the array without mutation:

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()
```

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
#=> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

shuffled_x = x[rng.permutation(x.size)]
#=> array([5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7, 0, 8])
```